# What should be done with answers that become invalidated b/c the question was rolled back

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

This question was originally posted as a revision of another question but was rolled back.

### Question

[Which image generating services don't duplicate copywritten work?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/270/12)

Content of [rev. 3](https://genai.stackexchange.com/revisions/270/3)

> ##### How can I know if an image generation tool might copy someone's art?
>
> I've read that the training sets and outputs of some generative AI services include copyrighted art. I'm interested in trying out image generators while not accidentally copying someone's art who hasn't intended for it to be used this way.
>
> How do I figure out how to use image generation services without abusing the rights of others? For example, I've tried to figure out which services make sure their training sets include images who's creators contributed the images intentionally.

---

### Answer

Link: https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/344/12

I think that "copy someone's art" cannot be determined in such a way that people who aren't art experts might determine.

On one side, the legal and ethical aspects are handled through intellectual property and authorship rights. On the other is the determination that copyright laws can limit what can be used and who and how to train an artificial intelligence entity.

It might help to look at the generative artificial intelligence operator documentation about their stand regarding intellectual property and authorship rights. Some organizations use a structure of [vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_statement), [mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_statement) and values or creed statements, long-term strategies and programs; others might have a "manifesto".

In the coming years, it is possible that the artificial intelligence industry will develop specific guidelines and practices around intellectual property and authorship rights. Simply stating that they operate within the law may not be enough.

Related

- [AI art tools Stable Diffusion and Midjourney targeted with copyright lawsuit](https://www.theverge.com/2023/1/16/23557098/generative-ai-art-copyright-legal-lawsuit-stable-diffusion-midjourney-deviantart)
- [Authors file a lawsuit against OpenAI for unlawfully ‘ingesting’ their books](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2023/jul/05/authors-file-a-lawsuit-against-openai-for-unlawfully-ingesting-their-books)

Answer (score 3):

> What should be done with answers that become invalidated b/c the question was rolled back

Ask the OP to post the question that the answer addressed as a new question (or do it yourself if OP isn't responding or uninterested), then have a mod move the answer there (or delete then repost the answer).

The new question is interesting, definitely worth posting as a new question.

Comment: "then have a mod move the answer there". Answers can only be converted to comments or (if a self answer) edits. It would have to be deleted and reposted, either by OP or maybe someone else (usually as a Community Wiki).

Comment: @Laurel Thanks, I didn't know. Can't mods move answers via merging questions? (e.g., couldn't a mod undelete question, merge questions, then re-delete question?)

Comment: Merging moves all the answers and cannot be reversed except by a developer. I guess a mod *could* duplicate the Q&A entirely by migrating it somewhere and back, but I would really consider that an abuse of the tooling. (It happened to [an answer of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlaok.png) by accident once.)

Answer (score 1):

Edits, including rollbacks, are not allowed to invalidate any existing answers.

The person who answered put work in and it's not fair for them to lose.

If someone who isn't the OP edited the question then it's fair to unroll it (rollback the rollback); this can be done by the answerer, it's not a biased edit it's the rules established on MSE.

If the OP has a change of plans and there's an answer they shouldn't edit their question and ruin another's work; they aren't required to accept it or vote on it either.

If the OP has a different question then they should simply ask a new question, they probably would want to point out the difference from their prior question (and link to it); so that it doesn't get flagged as a duplicate.

Once a rollback is rolled back, if there's any further rolls the moderator automatically gets notified; they will adjudicate the correct course of action.

Things like this have consistent rules across all the sites, so such questions don't need to be asked many times; you'll want to check the FAQ on the main Meta for answers to the most common questions.

Comment: "Once a rollback is rolled back, if there's any further rolls the moderator automatically gets notified". That's not the whole story. It requires two rollbacks by the same user within a single hour, which means the flag rarely shows up when it's needed. Please use a custom moderator flag if you actually want someone to look at it.

Comment: I realize @Laurel that you moderate a couple of sites but the advice from: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9187/188921 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322630/3648282 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/3648282 ChrisF says that re-rolling the roll results in an automated notification, and that the users should handle what they can without raising a flag; which will probably be declined. I wasn't aware of the one hour time limit, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The answer should be deleted as it's not answering the question of the current revision.